# Converting fluid simulation to key frames?

Tags: keyframes, fluid-simulation

Can you convert fluid simulation to key frames? I need to export my simulation from one blender file to another.

Comment: maybe you mean separate meshes? Maybe this will answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200210/fluid-how-to-convert-the-simulation-to-a-series-of-meshes

Comment: You can export as Alembic (.abc) and import https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185443/2214