# Fill Letter with Smoke - Smoke does not move

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, baking, smoke-simulation

I want to fill a letter with smoke. The letter is the effector (Physics/Fluids) and inside the letter there is a cube as emitter (Quick Smoke). The letter has flipped normals so the smoke should stay inside. (The Visibility of the letter is set to "Wire".) Unfortunately, the simulation doesn't do what I want at all. The smoke does not move at all. But it should fill the letter so that the shape is recognizable. Thanks for your tips!

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-6aoB2ctyy8)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea in Blender ...

Answer (score 0):

From testing it seems like ...

- sim is not happening for closed Effectors (Colliders)
- Normal orientation doesn't seems to be taken into a count as well
- you can cheat it by creating a hole in some area of your Effector and set as **Planar**

[image]

- sim starts to work with hole sized at least 5 domain's divisions. More divisions let you work with smaller hole. Why 5? I don't have a clue.

[image]

Anyway ... in general it is not a great idea to fill object by smoke because result ens up with jagged - stepped surface ... the only way I know - set extremely high domain resolution to try hide this issue ...

... or in theory - bake sim inside bigger effector and reuse baked data for original object with some a small hack – extra geometry (probably four vertices in dimension of bigger effector) just to fake the bounding box of bigger effector to prevent blender to resize voxel data into smaller (original) bounding box. If it wasn't clear I will try to attach some screens.
**Edit:** According to one my [previous post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91102/2214) this would not work either with Mantaflow solver (if there is not change) ... I didnt test it.